# Get all feathers UI selected check values

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have a function that loops through results from a remote database and it creates a number of check boxes a user can select.

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++)
{
   this.checkOption = new Check();
   this.checkOption.x = this.textQuad.x + 3;
   this.checkOption.y = this.textQuad.y + 3;
   this.checkOption.name = resultsArray[i].groupID;
}
```

and I also have a button to submit all the selected checks. My question is how can I get all the selected check names/values on a TRIGGERED event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your for-loop, `this.checkOption` will be set to each new `Check` object in turn and end up being set to the last one created. Obviously this is not very useful if you intend to retrieve any/all of the objects in future.

Instead, I would use a separate array to store the `Check` objects so that I can iterate them later:

```
private var checkboxes:Array;

...

checkboxes = new Array();
var checkOption:Check;
for(var i:int = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++)
{
   checkOption = new Check();
   checkOption.x = this.textQuad.x + 3;
   checkOption.y = this.textQuad.y + 3;
   checkOption.name = resultsArray[i].groupID;
   checkboxes.push(checkOption);
}
```

And, in your triggered event (obviously replace the `trace` with whatever you want to do with the values):

```
for(var checkbox:Check in checkboxes) {
   trace(checkbox.name + ": " + trace(checkbox.value);
}
```